# Only see "Laravel is installed successfully" page

Tags: php, laravel

I have edited a file and I uploaded it to the server. The only thing I can see is the Installed Successfully page on my website like something went really wrong. I have reverted the change on my file, which was `some.blade.php` in the `resources/views` directory, but the issue is still there. Has anyone faced the same issue?

The full webpage:

> Laravel is installed successfully.
>
> Laravel is a Framework and doesn't have an index page.
>
> You will be redirected to its "public" folder in 5 seconds...
>
> Laravel is a clean and classy framework for PHP web development.
>   Freeing you from spaghetti code, Laravel helps you create wonderful
>   applications using simple, expressive syntax. Development should be a
>   creative experience that you enjoy, not something that is painful.
>   Enjoy the fresh air.

Comment: Have you set up a route for the file?

Comment: Yes the route is there, was there since a lot time ago, I just change ther source for a jquery file. and then it start to show only this screen.

Comment: The error log shows:
 PHP Fatal error:  Illuminate\Routing\Router::loadRoutes(): Failed opening required 
 '/home/username/public_html/test/config/projectname/routes/api.php'
 (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php71/usr/share/pear') 
 in /home/username/public_html/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php on line 394

Comment: In your `routes` directory is the a file called `api.php` and if so are there any errors in the file?